# Airflow Task Potentially Running Duplicated in Kubernetes - How to Confirm?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm currently using Apache Airflow with the Kubernetes Executor and I've noticed some suspicious behavior that makes me think a task might be running duplicated in Kubernetes. I'm trying to understand if this is the case and if so, why it's happening.

My main suspicion comes from watching the following logs while checking my pods

```
➜  ~ kubectl get pods -n scheduler
NAME                                                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
da-job-boards-pipeline-jobs-normalisation-task-job-title-492abcde   1/1     Running   0          29h
da-job-boards-pipeline-jobs-normalisation-task-locations-tkaabcde   1/1     Running   0          28h
scheduler-scheduler-58f557f548-abcde                                2/2     Running   0          6d14h
scheduler-statsd-7dd4494d4f-abcde                                   1/1     Running   0          13d
scheduler-triggerer-0                                               2/2     Running   0          8d
scheduler-webserver-5546b8dd66-abcde                                1/1     Running   0          3d6h
➜  ~ kubectl get pods -n airflow
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jobs-normalisation-job-title-2bpsbabc   1/1     Running   0          29h
jobs-normalisation-locations-nv670abc   1/1     Running   0          28h
```

Also, the logs are the same in:

- `jobs-normalisation-job-title-2bpsbabc` and `da-job-boards-pipeline-jobs-normalisation-task-job-title-492abcde`
- `jobs-normalisation-locations-nv670abc` and `da-job-boards-pipeline-jobs-normalisation-task-locations-tkaabcde`

### CONFIGURATIONS

Here's the relevant configuration from my `airflow.cfg`:

```ini
[kubernetes]
airflow_configmap = scheduler-airflow-config
airflow_local_settings_configmap = scheduler-airflow-config
multi_namespace_mode = True
namespace = scheduler
pod_template_file = /opt/airflow/pod_templates/pod_template_file.yaml
worker_container_repository = SECRET.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/airflow
worker_container_tag = efeb_THIS_IS_A_TAG

[kubernetes_executor]
multi_namespace_mode = True
namespace = scheduler
pod_template_file = /opt/airflow/pod_templates/pod_template_file.yaml
worker_container_repository = SECRET.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/airflow
worker_container_tag = efeb_THIS_IS_A_TAG

[logging]
colored_console_log = False
delete_worker_pods = False
encrypt_s3_logs = True
logging_level = INFO
remote_base_log_folder = s3://scheduler-SECRET-eu-west-1/airflow/logs
remote_log_conn_id = aws_conn
remote_logging = True
```

In my DAG, I'm using the `KubernetesPodOperator` and these are the arguments that I suspect might be causing the tasks to duplicate:

```py
    'node_selector': {"abcd.com/tenant": "scheduler"},
    'tolerations': [k8s.V1Toleration(key="abcd.com/tenant", operator="Equal", value="scheduler")],
    'namespace': "airflow",
    'service_account_name': "airflow",
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights on whether these configurations might lead to duplicated task runs in Kubernetes? How can I confirm if the task is indeed running duplicated?

Comment: I saw your [other question the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77360720) and I'm quite curious about this myself. I won't be of any help, since I've never used a Kubernetes executor, but looking at your logs in that other question, I suspect the scheduler could be picking up the logs of the worker pod and outputting them again (notice how the logs in the scheduler are the same as your worker's with timestamps and level prepended to them). Would it be possible for you to alter the code to output something unique? Something like `print(uuid.uuid4())` and see if it's the same in both logs?

Comment: The thing is that there is a slight variation in the milliseconds in the logs, that made me suspect that we were probably duplicating the execution of the tasks, also the presence in 2 different namespaces at the time (I understand that it is due to the variables: namespace and node_selector

Comment: Another thing, I believe its helpful is that logs are being saved once only, a duplicate task should save them twice (I believe). This is the relevant variable within airflow.cfg: remote_base_log_folder = s3://analytics...

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: What I meant about the logs is that the second message seems to be a wrap of the first message just 2 ms. apart. As in: first there is a `time 1 | message` log and then, 2ms. later, `time2 {pod_manager.py} time 1 | message` as if the `pod_manager.py` had just picked up the first log message, wrapped it in its own logging format and re-printed it 2ms. later. Notice that the timestamp `14:23:14,120` remains consistent in both log messages. I mean... it _looks_ like you're seeing the exact same log message but printed by two different entities (to me!, I could be wrong!!) .